# Set value to model instance - ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net

i have an error while I set value to model instance

Controller

```
var operatingDTO = new List<OperatingDTO>();

      operatingDTO[0].Id = 1;
```

Model

```
public class OperatingDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Error

> 'operatingDTO[0].Id' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Comment: If you’ve just instantiated the list, there’s no item at index 0. You need to add an item before you can reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiated the element and then add to the list. There is a whole guide about that: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

> C# lets you instantiate an object or collection and perform member assignments in a single statement.

Replace with either

```
var operatingDTO = new List<OperatingDTO>();
operatingDTO.Add(new OperatingDTO { Id = 0 });
```

or even

```
var operatingDTO = new List<OperatingDTO> { new OperatingDTO { Id = 0 } };
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dktgq4)